# Can btrfs handle different RAID levels for different subvolumes?

Tags: btrfs

I'd like to assign different RAID levels to different subvolumes in my btrfs filesystem, eg have a subvolume /home that uses RAID 1 and a subvolume /var that uses RAID 0. Is that at all possible (if so, how?) or do I have to rely on separate filesystems / partitions to achieve this?

Comment: IIRC BTRFS does RAID between block devices. To get RAID for a particular filesystem hierarchy you would need to use LVM and only do the desired RAID level for a logical volume. All the `-m raid*` options to `mkfs.btrfs` appear to take block devices as arguments as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just cross-posted this question to the developers on linux-btrfs@kernel.org, and I've got the following answer from Hugo Mills:

> No, not yet.
>
> It's planned at some point (probably in the fairly distant future),
>   but hasn't arrived yet.